# Spring boot with embedded tomcat + access log with authentication user

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I'm using spring boot with embedded tomcat + spring security. 
My access log from tomcat seems like this

IP - - [14/Feb/2017:08:49:50 +0200] "GET /page/2 HTTP/1.1" 200 2606

So, how can i make log file to looks like

IP - - [14/Feb/2017:08:49:50 +0200]  **username** - "GET /page/2 HTTP/1.1" 200 2606

Every request have to have the username from which is made. For security authentication i'm using spring security with database username and password info.

Comment: Nice question, btw

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably need to change [access log pattern](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) in application properties to something like this:

```
server.tomcat.accesslog.pattern=%h %l %t %u "%r" %s %b
```

where `%u` is *Remote user that has been authenticated* (see example [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/tomcat/tomcat-access-log-configuration-example/)).

---

**UPD**: Possibly this is not sufficient as *common* pattern already contains `%u` parameter. In this case I would recommend two additional steps:

1. Put user's name into request session parameter, something like:

`request.getSession().setAttribute("username", user.getName());`

2. Add following parameter in access log pattern: `%{username}s`

   server.tomcat.accesslog.pattern=%h %l %t %u %{username}s "%r" %s %b

which should take attribute named `username` from `HttpSession` as it described [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/AccessLogValve.html).

Comment: How to deal with STATELESS session policy with this solution? Any ideas?

Comment: above approach seems to work for stateless also if added in a request filter (ex jwt validator). Alternatively you can set the attribute in the request like `request.setAttribute("username", user.getName());` and use `%{username}r`.

Comment: This stateless solution did not work here. As a matter of fact, the first request using session also didn't work. I can only imagine that the request came in and got registered in the accesslog before any filter could do anything. The following requests using the same session worked.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a full example of how I managed to do this. Since the existing answer didn't provide a very detailed explanation on how to obtain this goal.

In your spring web security config type following lines.

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .addFilterAfter(usernameAccessLogFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .build();
}

@Bean
    public UsernameAccessLogFilter usernameAccessLogFilter(){
        return new UsernameAccessLogFilter();
    }
```

Then create a custom filter:

```
public class UsernameAccessLogFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = ((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest);

    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if(authentication != null) {
        request.getSession().setAttribute("user", authentication.getName());
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
}
```

}

In your properties file (.yml format) add following:

```
server:
  tomcat:
    accesslog:
      enabled: true
      directory: logs
      pattern: "%t %a %A %r %s %u %{user}s %B %T %I"
    basedir: .
```

This was everything I had to do to obtain the above result.